# Limit of Lerch function $\Phi(z,1,a)$ as $z\to\infty$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions

The Lerch transcendent function is defined (see e.g. [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function)) by
$$
\Phi(z,s,a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(n+a)^s},
$$
which is convergent for complex $z$ with $|z|<1$. It can be analytically continued to the whole complex $z$ plane, except a cut on $[1,+\infty)$, by the integral
$$
\Phi(z,s,a)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty
\frac{t^{s-1}e^{-at}}{1-ze^{-t}}dt.
$$

**Question**:

I would like to show that $\Phi(z,1,a)\to0$ as $z$ goes to complex infinity with the assumption that $0<a\le1$.

**My approach**:

Using the identity
$$
\frac{1}{1-ze^{-t}}=1+\frac{ze^{-t}}{1-ze^{-t}}
$$
the integral can be rewritten as
$$
\Phi(z,1,a)=\int_0^\infty dt\,e^{-at}+
\int_0^\infty dt\,e^{-at}\frac{ze^{-t}}{1-ze^{-t}}.
$$
The first term is just $a^{-1}$ and in the second term I can take the $z\to\infty$ limit under the integral to find (at leading order)
$$
\Phi(z,1,a)\sim a^{-1}-a^{-1}=0,\qquad(z\to\infty).
$$
This proves what I wanted but I am still skeptical whether this is correct; interestingly neither Maple nor Mathematica could calculate this.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Mathematica returns unevaluated `Limit[HurwitzLerchPhi[z, 1, a], z -> Infinity], but for concrete a > 0, for example Limit[HurwitzLerchPhi[z, 1, 1/2], z -> Infinity] or Limit[HurwitzLerchPhi[z, 1, 2], z -> Infinity]` I got the result of zero.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my result.